# How to configure load balancer on a Asp.net core app hosted as a windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-services

I have an ASP.NET Core application deployed on two servers that are listening on two different IP addresses. Now I want to bind both of them to the same URL so that DNS can load balance the requests. How do I go about this configuration in my ASP.NET hosted as windows service?

Comment: Hi @Khuzaima jamil, what do you mean for `How do I go about this configuration in my Asp.net hosted as windows service?`? What you said above seems it should not be configured in asp.net core application.

Comment: I can setup hostname bindings on IIS, but since this is hosted as a windows service want to know how can i do bindings on this case.